# Scrapy returns unupdated data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm creating a product monitor for a website, but I ran into an issue. When crawling, Scrapy doesnt get the updated version of the site. When I crawl while its in stock, the json data from the site returns OutOfStock. If I check the website from my browser, the JSON variable is InStock. If I cURL the website, the JSON variable is InStock.

If I check a product which is always in stock with scrapy, the JSON variable returns InStock.

I tried different settings with spiders, and nothing worked.

I also tried using the `scrapy fetch` command, and scraping in a scrapy shell but nothing gave me the updated JSON data.

The JSON data is in a ld+json script element on the website.

This is the site im trying to scrape: https://www.target.com/p/meshmonitors/-/A-79659825

Comment: Please update the question with the page that you're crawling.

Comment: @Joaquin i added it

Comment: > If I check a product which is always in stock with scrapy, the JSON variable returns InStock.
You mean outOfStock right?

Comment: @Joaquin, basically if an item is in stock, it returns InStock. If an item is out of stock, it returns OutOfStock. If an item that was out of stock recently went in stock, the variable on the json changes to InStock, but scrapy still gets OutOfStock. cURL gets InStock though.